# need to generate an ordered table to match my ordered bar chart

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm summarizing a data set that has been grouped by two variables.  I recently learned how to reorder the bar chart according to my total count for the primary grouped variable.  I'd now like to generate a reordered table of data to match the re-ordered bar chart.  Here's what I have for the bar chart:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
df <- mtcars
df$gear <- as.factor(df$gear)
df$carb <- as.factor(df$carb)
car_summary <- df %>% group_by(carb, gear) %>% summarize(Count = n())
ggplot(data = car_summary, aes(x = reorder(carb, Count, sum), y = Count, fill = gear)) + 
  geom_col() + coord_flip() + labs(x = "carb", y = "Count")
```

[Ordered Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngyKY.png)

If I then try to generate a table to summarize the data the same way that the plot was generated I get:

```
summary_table <- df %>% group_by(carb, gear) %>% summarize(Count = n())
summary_table
```

However this gives me the following output:

```
> summary_table
# A tibble: 11 x 3
# Groups:   carb [?]
   carb  gear  Count
   <fct> <fct> <int>
 1 1     3         3
 2 1     4         4
 3 2     3         4
 4 2     4         4
 5 2     5         2
 6 3     3         3
 7 4     3         5
 8 4     4         4
 9 4     5         1
10 6     5         1
11 8     5         1
```

What I would like to see instead is the rows ordered so that the groups of `carb` variable are listed in order of their total sum accross all `gear` variables.  This is what my bar chart output looks like when I used the `reorder(carb, Count, sum)` statement.

I would like my `summary_table` to look like this:

```
> summary_table
# A tibble: 11 x 3
# Groups:   carb [?]
   carb  gear  Count
   <fct> <fct> <int>
 1 4     3         5
 2 4     4         4
 3 4     5         1
 4 2     3         4
 5 2     4         4
 6 2     5         2
 7 1     3         3
 8 1     4         4
 9 3     3         3
10 8     5         1
11 6     5         1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close, you just need to order the data in your table!  FWIW, if you find yourself doing `group(x,y) %>% summarize(count = n())` you can just use `count(df, x, y)` to save yourself some code.

```
car_summary <- count(mtcars, carb, gear)

summary_table <- car_summary %>% 
  group_by(carb) %>%
  mutate(nn = sum(n)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(nn), desc(carb)) %>% 
  select(-nn)

ggplot(data = car_summary, aes(x = reorder(carb, n, sum), y = n, fill = gear)) + 
  geom_col() + coord_flip() + labs(x = "carb", y = "Count")
```

summary_table looks like:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 3
# Groups:   carb [6]
    carb  gear     n
   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1  4.00  3.00     5
 2  4.00  4.00     4
 3  4.00  5.00     1
 4  2.00  3.00     4
 5  2.00  4.00     4
 6  2.00  5.00     2
 7  1.00  3.00     3
 8  1.00  4.00     4
 9  3.00  3.00     3
10  8.00  5.00     1
11  6.00  5.00     1
```

Comment: Perfect.  This is just what I needed.  Thank you.